# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, crashlytics, android-multidex, crashlytics-android

For the issue I have tried many solutions in many ways but wasn't able to solve.I have made my project as multidex enabled and application extends by MultiDexApplication.

There is

> **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/crashlytics/android/beta/Beta issue**

I tried to apply proguard rules inside to keep this class but same old same no success after at all.

I am very confused what is the issue inside that.

here are my dependencies in the application's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    //  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '../../libs/')
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar') {
        // exclusion is not neccessary, but generally a good idea.
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.0.2'
    compile project(':FlipLibrary')
    compile project(':SubsamplingImageView')
    compile('de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile('com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar') {
        // exclusion is not neccessary, but generally a good idea.
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.1'
    compile project(':NewFlipLibrary')
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.273.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.2'
    //    compile 'se.emilsjolander:android-flipview:+'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
    //fordatabse
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    compile files('libs/craftar-on-device-image-recognition-sdk-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/sanselan-0_97-android-1.0.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
}
```

and below is whole crash log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/crashlytics/android/beta/Beta;
                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:29)
                                                                 at cz.ackee.cubeplatform.App.onCreate(App.java:59)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1016)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4795)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:176)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.package-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:29) 
                                                                 at cz.ackee.cubeplatform.App.onCreate(App.java:59) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1016) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4795) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:176) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751) 
                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta
                                                                 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                        ... 14 more
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

As above is my dependancies and crash log added

Comment: Can you make your CardView also v7:26.0.1' instead of 25.3.1 .

Comment: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html you followed this?

Comment: post your entire build.gradle please

Comment: as above I have provided gradle dependancy. Which part I need to add from build.gradle because it's too large.Thank you sunil I change it. Thank you Aswin P Ashok, I have checked link and as per suggested that proguard rules i have added still not working by the way i haven't make minifyEnabled true.

Comment: I am getting this crash on lollipop 5.0. above 5.0 it's working and my minimum sdk is 5.0

Comment: look at there and check that your build.gradle match https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Comment: Yes I have done same as this linkl : https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Comment: do us a favour and put your error logcat complete here please so that we could see more instead of the name of exception only!

Comment: I have added entire crash log please check updated my question

Comment: @SameerJani Can you try adding this 

`dexOptions {
            incremental true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }`

Comment: @sunilsunny, Yes I have put it.

Comment: And ? Also I believe you are installing multidex in your application right ? Like this `MultiDex.install(this);`

Comment: Yes I have, But done by extending MultidexApplication.

Comment: Can you share your Fabric init code please?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating all the dependencies and also update your Google play services.
And make sure defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
      } in your gradle

Comment: Have you checked my question??